# How to block Send in TCP if already contain data in buffer to process at client side

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have been using `TCP sockets` to send and recieve data from server to client.

I am using following code

**Server**

```
 private string SendDataToClient(int currentStationSeq, int nextStationSeq, int SequenceOrder)
    {          
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", currentStationSeq, nextStationSeq, SequenceOrder));
        Socket workerSocket = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_workerSocketList.Count; i++)
        {
            workerSocket = (Socket)m_workerSocketList[i];
            if (workerSocket != null)
            {
                if (workerSocket.Connected)
                {
                    workerSocket.Send(byData);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

**Client**

```
 public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
            int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];              
            string szData = new string(chars);
            //Console.WriteLine(szData);
            string[] arrData = szData.Split(',');
            if (arrData.Length == 3)
            {
               // Some code
            }
            else if (arrData.Length == 2)
            {
                // Some Code
            }
            else if (arrData.Length == 1)
            {
            }
            WaitForData();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

        }
    }
```

It works fine when `Server` not sending continuously. But in case when `Server` send data faster than `Client` process it, data gets starting to accumulate in buffer. When `client` reads it from buffer, it reads all data from buffer, thus break my logic.

I need something like if `Server` send data to `client`, it must wait for data to process at `client` side before sending any new data.

How it is possible ??

Comment: "When client reads it from buffer, it reads all data from buffer, thus break my logic." - it sounds like you're expecting *messaging* rather than *streaming*. If you want messaging on TCP, it's up to *you* to implement it or to move to a higher level abstraction which implements it for you. (Common ways to implement are fixed size messages, marker bytes or length-prefixed messages - but the golden rule is never expect calls to `Send` on one side to be matched 1-1 with calls to `Receive` at the other side)